# Generate Unique ID from varchar column in T SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that I want to join.
Both tables are containing some varchar columns that I use to join them.
However, running queries to make calculations using varchar columns in order to join, is a slow process.
So, I would like to transform these varchar columns to unique integer ids so the comparison will be faster.

```
SELECT /*do calculations*/
FROM   [dbo].[messages]  m WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN   [dbo].[jointable] j ON j.address = m.orig OR j.address = m.recip
```

The address, orig and recip are the column which have strings and would be better to have ids to make performance faster.
I realise that the part `ON j.address = m.orig OR j.address = m.recip` slows performance.

The tables that i want to join have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jointable](
    [displayname] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [alias] [nvarchar](129) NULL,
    [firstname] [nvarchar](129) NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](129) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [company] [nvarchar](129) NULL,
    [department] [nvarchar](129) NULL,
    [office] [nvarchar](129) NULL) 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[messages](
    [messageid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [message] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [orig] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [recip] [nvarchar](256) NULL)
```

How can I do this? Is there any function that I can convert an id from varchar to integer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could also try if it helps to create indexes on the varchar values of both tables. At least then you won't have to worry about keeping the `varchar` -> `unique value` mapping in good working order.

Comment: Side note: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: Post the query plan and tables schema

Comment: Are you looking to do a one off exercise to create an ID column which can then be used to make future queries faster (recommended), or are you looking to create a function to convert hash the address to another value at runtime for comparison; if the latter, why?

Comment: @JohnLBevan I am looking to create instead of a varchar id, that we already have, an integer id for orig and recip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) data in your tables
2. Add int primary key to the first table
3. Add int foreign key to the second table. Set corresponding value from the first table
4. Join by int keys

Comment: What about when some later changes on or both of the values?  Values in the first table might not be unique.

Comment: @paparazzo: 2.5. Normalize your database ;)

Comment: @paparazzo good advice by JohnLBevan, you should use normalized  tables

Comment: @Backs I don't have a question here.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** *generated a GUID from a VARCHAR*, but I doubt, you are happy with this (so you will need some kind of mapping table as suggested in other answers). Just to show the principles:

If your strings are short and unique within 16 bytes this might work for you:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeString VARCHAR(100),TheGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);

--a GUID is a 16-Byte(128 bit) sized type

INSERT INTO @tbl(SomeString) VALUES
 ('test1')
,('Some short text')
,('Some very very very very long text')
,('Some very very very very long text which is the same as the other one in the first 16 bytes');

UPDATE @tbl SET TheGUID=CAST(CAST(SomeString AS VARBINARY(16)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);

SELECT SomeString
      ,TheGUID
      ,CAST(CAST(TheGUID AS VARBINARY(16)) AS VARCHAR(16))
FROM @tbl;
```

The result (scroll to the side)

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
| SomeString                                                                                  | TheGUID                              | (Kein Spaltenname) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
| test1                                                                                       | 74736574-0031-0000-0000-000000000000 | test1              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Some short text                                                                             | 656D6F53-7320-6F68-7274-207465787400 | Some short text    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Some very very very very long text                                                          | 656D6F53-7620-7265-7920-766572792076 | Some very very v   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Some very very very very long text which is the same as the other one in the first 16 bytes | 656D6F53-7620-7265-7920-766572792076 | Some very very v   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: @alexithymia And please do your part to make SO effective by marking the response as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First try to add indexes on your columns (even if they are `VARCHAR`). If you are still struggling with performance, you can use the following to join by integer values.

```
-- Create a table to link a varchar with an integer
CREATE TABLE WordIndex(
    WordID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Word VARCHAR(500))

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_WordIndex_Word ON WordIndex (Word)
GO

-- Load the table with all available words
INSERT INTO WordIndex (
    Word)
SELECT DISTINCT
    YourVarcharColumn
FROM
    YourTable
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    YourOtherVarcharColumn
FROM
    YourSecondTable

GO


-- Add the integer ID to your tables
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD WordID INT
ALTER TABLE YourSecondTable ADD WordID INT

ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (WordID) REFERENCES WordIndex (WordID)
ALTER TABLE YourSecondTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (WordID) REFERENCES WordIndex (WordID)
GO

-- Optionally (but recommended) add indexes on the ID
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_YourTable_WordID ON YourTable (WordID)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_YourSecondTable_WordID ON YourSecondTable (WordID)
GO


-- Update the integer ID
UPDATE T SET
    WordID = W.WordID
FROM
    YourTable AS T
    INNER JOIN WordIndex AS W ON T.Word = W.Word

UPDATE T SET
    WordID = W.WordID
FROM
    YourSecondTable AS T
    INNER JOIN WordIndex AS W ON T.Word = W.Word
GO


-- Join by integer
SELECT
    1
FROM
    YourTable AS T
    INNER JOIN YourSecondTable AS N ON T.WordID = N.WordID
```

Using this approach requieres maintaining the word index table.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see table design to properly answer.

If you just add int for the relationship and properly assign the int the problem is if you later change the data then the int relationship is wrong.

If you index those columns a varchar join is not much faster than int.

Would likely be the same query plan but

```
SELECT /*do calculations*/
FROM   [dbo].[messages]  m 
JOIN   [dbo].[jointable] j ON j.address in (m.orig, m.recip)
```